# How to quit in a void function in Android?

Tags: java, android, return

I hope the system can quit the void function `HandlePost` when meet a condition Case 1, so I add `return` after `DoSomething1()`.

But Android Studio tell me the info  'return' is unncessery as last statement in a 'void' method!

```
private void HandlePost(IHTTPSession session){
    try {

        Map<String, String> files = new HashMap<String, String>();
        session.parseBody(files);

        //Case 1
        String deleteValue=session.getParms().get("ActionDelete");
        if (deleteValue!=null){
           DoSomething1();
           return;
        }

        //Case 2
        String copyValue=session.getParms().get("ActionCopy");
        if (copyValue!=null){
           DoSomething2();
            return;
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Utility.LogError("This is an error "+e.getMessage() );
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of returning, you could just put "case 2" in an `else if` block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `return` statement is unnecessary if it is the last (executed) statement in the method. You can either ignore the warning or remove the statement. Note: The first `return` in your example *is* necessary but the second isn't.

You can completely avoid returns in your method, if you put *Case 2* in an `else` block.

Answer (score 1):

Whilst I agree that the second `return` statement is not entirely required, I disagree that this should be a warning, it makes sense for you to keep it.

I've seen bugs introduced by this kind of a over-zealous warning, if you remove that return statement then you are removing an important intent of the method.  This is fine for now, but it makes it too easy for someone to come along in the future and add more functionality to the bottom of this method and potentially cause problems.

My suggestion would be to ignore this warning in this specific case.

Comment: Whilst I agree with most of your answer, I strongly disagree with your last sentence. In this specific case, he can easily solve this without any return statements if he just uses if-else or switch statements (even though the latter might require a bit more rethinking of the basic design). Which would not only resolve the warning but also prevent him from removing that important intent AND even make sure new programmers won't have to think about where to put returns and where not to if they just want to add more cases.

Comment: @Mark I completely agree

Answer (score 0):

Remove `return;` statement after

```
DoSomething2();
```

And Lint will not raise any problems

Comment: It would be better to explain the OP why the lint appears instead of telling to do what the lint does. That's why he is asking